# Segmentation fault Core Dumped X86 Assembly Array

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I asked for help earlier and thought I was home free but I'm not. My logic was wrong and I've greatly altered it. This program is supposed to return the Max int in the array (which also happens to be the last element). After tracing it with GDB a few times, I see that I get to the 5th (2nd to last) element in the array, "20", when I hit a segmentation fault and the program halts. I set ECX to the array length and subtracted 1 from ECX to avoid this, but my logic is obviously wrong. Am I wrong in depending on the ECX counter to terminate the loop. Any ideas please?

***EDIT MAJOR EDITS TO CODE

```
SECTION .data   ;data section
msg1: db "Here are the array elements:", 10, 0
msg1Len: equ $-msg1
msg2: db "Here is the sorted array:", 10, 0
msg2Len: equ $-msg2



arr: dd 12, 16, 6, 18, 10, 40, 30
arrLen: equ ($-arr)/4   ;number of elements = array length / 4

SECTION .bss
max resd 1 ;declare and reserve space for max


SECTION .text

    global bsort
bsort:
    push ebp ; save old ebp register
    mov ebp, esp ; build a new stack
restart:
    mov ebx, arr ; the base address argument is saved in ebx register
    mov ecx, arrLen ; the size argument is saved in exc register
    sub ecx, 1 ; Last member has no following element to compare with.
    ; So we need to reduce the counter by 1
top:
    mov eax, [ebx] ;; access first array element. Move its value to eax
    cmp eax, [ebx+4] ; compare the value of eax ([ebx]) with [ebx+4]
    jle noswap ; if value at eax is less or equal to value of [ebx+4]
    ; no need to exchang values. Jump to noswap
    xchg eax, [ebx+4] ; if value at eax > value [ebx+4], exchange
    mov [ebx], eax ; store the new exchanged value at [ebx]
    jmp restart ; reset the base address and counter. Start over
noswap:
    add ebx, 4 ; move to the next array element
    loop top ; loop back to the top if the register ecx > 0
    leave
    ret

global main
main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        mov ecx, msg1   ;print msg1
        mov edx, msg1Len
        call PString

        ;save array base address in ebx and save sizein in ecx
        mov ebx, arr
        mov ecx, arrLen; store num elements in ecx
        ;loop to print array
PrintArray:
        mov eax, [ebx] ;move value [ebx] to eax
        call PrintDec
        call Println
        add ebx, 4
        loop PrintArray

;call bubblesort
    call bsort

    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, msg2Len
    call PString

    ;save arr base add in sbx and size in ecx
    mov ebx, arr
    mov ecx, arrLen
PrintSortedArray:
    mov eax, [ebx]
    call PrintDec
    call Println
    add ebx, 4
    loop PrintSortedArray 

        ;exit program and clean stack
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret

PString:; save register values of the called function
    pusha
    mov eax,4 ; use 'write' system call = 4
    mov ebx,1 ; file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
    int 80h ; call the kernel

    ; restore the old register values of the called function
    popa
    ret

Println:
    ;will call PString func
    ;will change content of ecx and edx
    ;need to save registers used by the main program
    section .data
    nl db 10
    section .text
    pusha

    mov ecx, nl
    mov edx, 1
    call PString

    ;return original register values
    popa
    ret

PrintDec:
;saves all registers so they return unmodified
;build the function to handle dword size

    section .bss
    decstr resb 10 ; 10 32-bit digits
    ct1 resd 1 ;keep track of dec-string size

    section .text
    pusha; save registers

    mov dword[ct1],0 ;initially assume 0
    mov edi, decstr ; edi points to dec-string
    add edi, 9 ; moved to the last element of string
    xor edx, edx ; clear edx for 64-bit div
whileNotZero:
    mov ebx, 10 ; get ready to divide by 10
    div ebx ; divide by 10
    add edx, '0' ; convert to ascii
    mov byte[edi], dl ; put it in string
    dec edi ; move to next char in str
    inc dword[ct1] ; inc char counter
    xor edx, edx ; clear edx
    cmp eax, 0  ;is remainder 0?
    jne whileNotZero ;if no, keep on looping

    inc edi ; conversion finished, bring edi
    mov ecx, edi ; back to start of string. make ecx
    mov edx, [ct1] ; point to counterm edx gets # chars
    mov eax, 4 ; print to stdout
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80 ; call kernel

    popa ; restore registers
    ret
```

Comment: Which instruction segfaults?  GDB shows you this.

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048444 in sameMax ()
(gdb) inf registers esi
esi            0x14 20
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function sameMax,
which has no line number information.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) q

Comment: `0x08048444` is the numeric address, but which asm instruction is that? 
 Is it the `mov eax, [esi]`?  That's the only memory access in `sameMax` other than call/branch.  Use GDB's `layout asm` / `layout reg` mode to make it easier to see, or just use `disas`.  If you want your code to have source line-number info, use `nasm -g -Fdwarf` to add debug info.  (See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more debugging tips.)

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048447 in printMax ()

Comment: student@student-linux:~/Desktop/wk12$ nasm -g -Fdwarf lab13a.asm -o lab13a.o
nasm: fatal: unrecognized debug format `dwarf' for output format `bin'
type `nasm -h' for help

Comment: You left out the other necessary NASM option,`-felf` or `-f elf32` which I assume you were already for builds without debug info.   The default output format is flat binary, which doesn't support debug info.